# template function to handle different array dimensions and data types in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, vector

can anybody teach me how to write a template function that can handle different array dimensions 1d,2d.is it possible? if possible give me an example on initializing the given array either 1d or 2d with zeros.

Comment: Why do you need a function for that? Just use an initializer when declaring the array.

Answer (score 2):

Following may help:

C++03:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void zero_array(T (&a)[N])
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        a[i] = 0;
    }
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2>
void zero_array(T (&a)[N1][N2])
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N1; ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j != N2; ++j) {
            a[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a[42];
    int b[42][2];

    zero_array(a);
    zero_array(b);

    return 0;
}
```

C++11 (any dimension):

```
#include <array>

template<typename T>
struct zero
{
    void operator () (T& t) const { t = 0; }
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct zero<std::array<T, N>>
{
    void operator () (std::array<T, N> &a) const
    {
        zero<T> z;
        for (auto& e : a) {
            z(e);
        }
    }
};

template <typename T>
void zero_array(T &a)
{
    zero<T>()(a);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::array<std::array<int, 42>, 2> a;

    zero_array(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it's pretty easy to do it:

c++11 (for any dimension!)

```
template< typename T >
void zero_out(T &cell)
{
    cell = T();
}
template< size_t N, typename T >
void zero_out(T(&array)[N]) // this function is called recursively for each array dimension 
{
    for (auto & cell : array)
    {
        zero_out(cell);
    }
}

void test()
{
    static int array[2][3][4][5];

    zero_out(array); // <--- zero out all the cells of our fourth-dimension array!
}
```

I think it's also doable the same way for C++03 (just avoid use of 'range-for' and 'auto').